# mxGetIr makes my Matlab crash

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

I am writing a MEX-file that involves reading a sparse matrix from Matlab, but Matlab crashes every time I ran the program. Then I write a test file, finding that the problem is exactly in the mxGetIr command. I have no idea why this happens. Please help me... Thank you very much!

I am working under Matlab 2013a in Mac OS X 10.8.1.

```
#include "fintrh.h"

  subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

  mwpointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
  integer nlhs, nrhs

  integer temp, nzmax
  integer, dimension(2) :: dimx

  real, dimension (:), allocatable :: sr
  integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: irs, jcs

  mwpointer mxGetPr
  mwpointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
  mwsize  mxGetM, mxGetN, mxGetNzmax

  mwpointer mxGetIr, mxGetJc

  mwpointer temp_pr, spr

  dimx(1) = mxGetM(prhs(1))
  dimx(2) = mxGetN(prhs(1))
  nzmax = mxGetNzmax(prhs(1))
  allocate(sr(1:nzmax))
  allocate(irs(1:nzmax))
  allocate(jcs(1:(dimx(2)+1)))
  temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
  call getreal(temp_pr,sr,nzmax)

  temp_pr = mxGetJc(prhs(1))

  plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nzmax,1,0)
  temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))
  call putreal(sr, temp_pr, nzmax)

  end

  subroutine real8toreal(x, y, size)
  integer size
  real*8 x(size)
  real y(size)
  do 10 i=1,size
     y(i)= x(i)
  10   continue
  return
  end

  subroutine getreal(pr,x,size)
  mwpointer pr
  integer size
  real x(size)
  real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: temp
  allocate(temp(1:size))
  call mxCopyPtrToReal8(pr,temp,size)
  call real8toreal(temp,x,size)
  deallocate(temp)      
  return
  end

  subroutine putreal(x,pr,size)
  mwpointer pr
  integer size
  real x(size)
  real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: temp
  allocate(temp(1:size))
  call realtoreal8(x,temp,size)
  call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(temp,pr,size)
  deallocate(temp)      
  return
  end
```

Comment: are you sure the input you provide to the function is indeed sparse? Use [`mxIsSparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxissparse.html) to check for it internally.

Comment: Thanks! I checked and it is a sparse matrix...

Answer (score 0):

After checking [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetir.html), I think you may need to call it differently.

From there I would guess something like this:

```
mwPointer mxGetIr(pm)
mwPointer pm
```